# Is there any U.S. or Western think-tank that predicted how long it would take for China to produce 5nm or 7nm chips without EUV?

Tags: united-states, china, technology

> SMIC managed to scrape together equipment from existing plants and
> those received before Washington’s sanctions to keep the 7nm
> production line going, say two sources close to SMIC’s suppliers.
>
> But this still left it without the additional support that ASML
> typically provides for customers of the highly complex machines. “The
> condition is harsh,” says one chip company executive close to SMIC.
> “Basically, no software updates and no equipment factory engineers to
> carry out maintenance services.”
>
> **US officials were surprised SMIC was able to acquire the spare parts
> and technical services needed to keep its 7nm production facility
> operational even after the export controls, says Allen.**

https://www.ft.com/content/327414d2-fe13-438e-9767-333cdb94c7e1

Is there any U.S. or Western think-tank that predicted how long it would take for China to produce 5nm chips without EUV? You would think that the U.S. government source their prediction somewhere, I am wondering if any think-tank made any prediction on this manner as most of their analyses are in the public domain. I would like to understand how they are basing their predictions.